# shardingsphere how to query specific sharding tables according to different conditions

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, sharding

I'm using [shardingsphere][1] with sprintboot.  the logic talbe order were sharding into two actual: order_0 and order_1,
while order_0 is for normal account and order_1 is for testing account.

now I would like to find a way to query specific table according to different role(testing account can only see data in order_1)
[1]: https://shardingsphere.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Sharding is for horizontal scale only, it is better to use sharding-key to split them.

Sharding is the one of feature in ShardingSphere, there are lots of other features in this project.

Around your requirement, it is better to use the shadow feature here.
The testing data will go to shadow database automatically, and normal table should go to online database.

FYI: https://github.com/apache/shardingsphere/tree/master/shardingsphere-features/shardingsphere-shadow